# ITK + VTK + Qt on VS2012 - Windows 8

Tags: windows, qt, vtk, itk

I am creating a project for Image Registration. I had to use windows 8 for executing it. I checked my code with Mac OSX it works perfectly but i have a problem in finding the headers i have used (ITK AND VTK) in Windows it was clearly available in usr/local/include in Mac. But after building the Qt and VTK AND ITK all in VS 2012 Professional 64 bit. I still couldnt find a way to include the headers in Qt Pro

My pro file looks like this

```
**#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-09-18T14:03:47
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ImageRegistration
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -L/C:/Toolkits/itk-4.4.2/bin/lib/Release/\
-lITKVtkGlue-4.4\
-lITKBiasCorrection-4.4\
-lITKBioCell-4.4\
-lITKCommon-4.4\
-lITKDICOMParser-4.4\
-litkdouble-conversion-4.4\
-lITKEXPAT-4.4\
-lITKFEM-4.4\
-litkgdcmCommon-4.4\
-litkgdcmDICT-4.4\
-litkgdcmDSED-4.4\
-litkgdcmIOD-4.4\
-litkgdcmjpeg8-4.4\
-litkgdcmjpeg12-4.4\
-litkgdcmjpeg16-4.4\
-litkgdcmMSFF-4.4\
-litkgdcmuuid-4.4\
-lITKgiftiio-4.4\
-litkhdf5_cpp-4.4\
-litkhdf5-4.4\
-lITKIOBioRad-4.4\
-lITKIOBMP-4.4\
-lITKIOCSV-4.4\
-lITKIOGDCM-4.4\
-lITKIOGE-4.4\
-lITKIOGIPL-4.4\
-lITKIOHDF5-4.4\
-lITKIOImageBase-4.4\
-lITKIOIPL-4.4\
-lITKIOJPEG-4.4\
-lITKIOLSM-4.4\
-lITKIOMesh-4.4\
-lITKIOMeta-4.4\
-lITKIONIFTI-4.4\
-lITKIONRRD-4.4\
-lITKIOPNG-4.4\
-lITKIOSiemens-4.4\
-lITKIOSpatialObjects-4.4\
-lITKIOStimulate-4.4\
-lITKIOTIFF-4.4\
-lITKIOTransformBase-4.4\
-lITKIOTransformHDF5-4.4\
-lITKIOTransformInsightLegacy-4.4\
-lITKIOTransformMatlab-4.4\
-lITKIOVTK-4.4\
-lITKIOXML-4.4\
-litkjpeg-4.4\
-lITKKLMRegionGrowing-4.4\
-lITKLabelMap-4.4\
-lITKMesh-4.4\
-lITKMetaIO-4.4\
-litkNetlibSlatec-4.4\
-lITKniftiio-4.4\
-lITKNrrdIO-4.4\
-litkopenjpeg-4.4\
-lITKOptimizers-4.4\
-lITKOptimizersv4-4.4\
-lITKPath-4.4\
-litkpng-4.4\
-lITKPolynomials-4.4\
-lITKQuadEdgeMesh-4.4\
-lITKReview-4.4\
-lITKSpatialObjects-4.4\
-lITKStatistics-4.4\
-litksys-4.4\
-litktiff-4.4\
-litkv3p_lsqr-4.4\
-litkv3p_netlib-4.4\
-litkvcl-4.4\
-lITKVideoCore-4.4\
-lITKVideoIO-4.4\
-litkvnl_algo-4.4\
-litkvnl-4.4\
-lITKVNLInstantiation-4.4\
-lITKVTK-4.4\
-lITKWatersheds-4.4\
-litkzlib-4.4\
-lITKznz-4.4

INCLUDEPATH+= C:/Toolkits/itk-4.4.2
DEPENDPATH+= C:/Toolkits/itk-4.4.2

LIBS += -L/C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/macos/ \
-lboost_filesystem\
-lboost_system\
-lhdf5\
-lhdf5_cpp\
-lscilscore\
-lscilsdomainmodel\
-lscilsgenericio\
-lscilshdf5io\
-llibz

INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/boost
DEPENDPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/boost

INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/scils
DEPENDPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/scils

INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/hdf5
DEPENDPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/hdf5

INCLUDEPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/hdf5-static
DEPENDPATH+=C:/Users/Venky/Desktop/Image_Registration_Files/ImageRegistration/hdf5-static


LIBS += -L/C:/Toolkits/vtk-5.10/bin/bin/Release/\
-lQVTK\
-lvtkalglib\
-lvtkCharts\
-lvtkCommon\
-lvtkDICOMParser\
-lvtkexoIIc\
-lvtkexpat\
-lvtkFiltering\
-lvtkfreetype\
-lvtkftgl\
-lvtkGenericFiltering\
-lvtkGeovis\
-lvtkGraphics\
-lvtkhdf5_hl\
-lvtkhdf5\
-lvtkHybrid\
-lvtkImaging\
-lvtkInfovis\
-lvtkIO\
-lvtkjpeg\
-lvtklibxml2\
-lvtkmetaio\
-lvtkNetCDF_cxx\
-lvtkNetCDF\
-lvtkpng\
-lvtkproj4\
-lvtkRendering\
-lvtksqlite\
-lvtksys\
-lvtktiff\
-lvtkverdict\
-lvtkViews\
-lvtkVolumeRendering\
-lvtkWidgets\
-lvtkzlib

INCLUDEPATH+= C:/Toolkits/vtk-5.10
DEPENDPATH+= C:/Toolkits/vtk-5.10

INCLUDEPATH+=$$PWD

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        ImageRegistrationImplementation.cpp\
listWidget.cpp\
overlayview.cpp \
transforms.cpp \
model.cpp \
imageviewer.cpp


HEADERS  += ImageRegistrationImplementation.h\
listWidget.h\
    overlayview.h \
    transforms.h \
    model.h \
    imageviewer.h


FORMS    += ImageRegistration.ui
**
```

I have included the installation directory of the ITK and VTK. I couldnt include the path where the headers are as i couldnt find everyone of them. I even tried copying the headers from my Mac to the the installed itk and vtk directory without any success. It would be great if anyone exactly tell me how to link the headers in Qt Creator.

Comment: don't you have source dir of ITK and VTK by which you build those libs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to include after building the "INSTALL" folder seperately